# How to implement callBack function when screen change in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, class-completion

I need a function when change screen executing, I mean when from screen home navigate to about screen  executing the callback function.

### Scenario

I want make global stack when change any naviagte run callback function for some check like (**userToken, internet state, check location is one or off, etc.**)

### Try this

i create a class component for **Stack-navigation** and implemnet `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate`, can detected any navigate.

**Code**

```
UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(prevProp, prevState) {
    if (prevProp != this.props) {
      console.log('change state navigation');
    }
  }
```

### Mistake this way

- Can not detected first screen `index-zero` **Home-screen**.
- I must write for each stack this code.

### My Stack

```
<Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Home}
    />
   <Stack.Screen
      name="About"
      component={About}
    />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current route with "onNavigationStateChange" prop in "NavigationContainer"

[React Navigation 4.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/)

```
onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
    const currentScreen = this.getCurrentRouteName(currentState);
    const prevScreen = this.getCurrentRouteName(prevState);
}}

// gets the current screen from navigation state
function getCurrentRouteName(navigationState) {
  if (!navigationState) {
    return null;
  }
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
  // dive into nested navigators
  if (route.routes) {
    return getCurrentRouteName(route);
  }
  return route.routeName;
}
```

[React Navigation 5.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/)

```
<NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name}
      onStateChange={() => {
        const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name

        if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
          // The line below uses the expo-firebase-analytics tracker
          // https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-analytics/
          // Change this line to use another Mobile analytics SDK
          Analytics.setCurrentScreen(currentRouteName);
        }

        // Save the current route name for later comparision
        routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
      }}
 >
   {/* ... */}
 </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks, `onStateChange` exactly it needed, but when access props in   `onStateChange` callBack function alredy is empty array, why ?

Comment: How are you using props in onStateChange?

Comment: I used `this.props`, i want get navigation object from props

Answer (score 0):

for React Navigation 5.x

```
<NavigationContainer
  onStateChange={(st) => {
      let routeName = st.routes[st.index].name
      /* your other code */
  }}>
</NavigationContainer>
```